# problema de escritura y lectura de objeto en un fichero binario

Tags: java, java-swing, archivo, interfaz-gráfica, serialización

Tengo una aplicación que me debe permitir dar de alta médicos y listarlos, estos médicos se irán agregando a un archivo que podrá ser leido.

El archivo en cuestión es un archivo serializable.

El problema que tengo es que cuando le doy a guardar el médico el archivo no contiene datos y cuando le doy a mostrar no me muestra nada, el archivo uando lo abro contiene un null.

Tengo una duda, y no sé si es por el interfaz o bien por la implementación de los métodos.

creo que el problema es que no me escribe en el archivo el objeto que estoy creando.

Os adjunto código:

1) Os paso la clase "medicos" (Hay un problema porque aunque le doy a implements serializable no me adjunta un serial version ID específico)

```
package tarea07grafica;

import java.io.Serializable;



public class medicos implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//declaramos los atributos       
private String NIF;
private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private int telefono;
private String sexo;
private boolean guardias;
private String especialidad;

//creamos el constructor por defecto
public medicos(){

}

//creamos el constructor
public medicos(String NIF, String nombre, String apellidos, int telefono, String sexo, boolean guardias, String especialidad) {
    this.NIF = NIF;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.guardias = guardias;
    this.especialidad = especialidad;
}


//creamos los getter y setter
public String getNIF() {
    return NIF;
}

public void setNIF(String NIF) {
    this.NIF = NIF;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

public boolean isGuardias() {
    return guardias;
}

public void setGuardias(boolean guardias) {
    this.guardias = guardias;
}

public String getEspecialidad() {
    return especialidad;
}

public void setEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
    this.especialidad = especialidad;
}


//creamos el metodo toString
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "medicos= " + "NIF: " + NIF + ", nombre: " + nombre + ", apellidos: " + apellidos + ", telefono: " + telefono + ", sexo: " + sexo + ", guardias: " + guardias + ", especialidad: " + especialidad;
}
```

}

2) Ahora os paso la clase donde manejo los archivos (no sé si está planteada correctamente por los errores que me da en la lectura)

```
public class Tarea07Grafica {   


    private void leerArchivo(){

        medicos m;
        String NIF, nombre, apellidos, telefono, sexo, guardias, especialidad;

        try {
            FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream("medicos.txt");//abrimos el flujo de entrada
            ObjectInputStream lectura = new ObjectInputStream(archivo);//usamos el ObjectInputStream para leer objetos del archivo
            //recorremos el archivo  
            while(true){
                m = (medicos) lectura.readObject();
                NIF = m.getNIF();
                nombre = m.getNombre();
                apellidos = m.getApellidos();
                telefono = String.valueOf(m.getTelefono());
                sexo = String.valueOf(m.getSexo());
                guardias = String.valueOf(m.isGuardias());
                especialidad = String.valueOf(m.getEspecialidad());

            }
            //capturamos las excepciones
            }catch (EOFException ex){
            System.err.println("Error " + ex);                    
            }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error, " + ex);                
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error, " + ex);
        }
    }

    public void añadirDatos(){            

        try {
           FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream ("medicos.txt", true);//abrimos el flujo de salida
            try (ObjectOutputStream escritura = new ObjectOutputStream(archivo)) {//usamos el ObjectOutputStream para escribir objetos en el archivo
                medicos m = new medicos();//creamos el objeto 
                escritura.writeObject(m); //escribimos objetos en el archivo
                escritura.close();//cerramos el archivo
            }
        //capturamos las excepciones
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error," + ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error, " + ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Tarea07Grafica archivo = new Tarea07Grafica();
        Interfaz Interfaz = new Interfaz();
        Interfaz.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Interfaz.setTitle("Ventana Principal");
        Interfaz.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

3) Y ahora os adjunto el código de los métodos de la interfaz gráfica que creo que me están dando problemas (lo que quiero que el botón mostrar implemente el añadirDatos en la ventana de manejo de archivo,es decir, que me escriba.

```
private void btnMostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


    File archivo = new File("medicos.dat");//inicializamos el objeto de tipo File

    medicos m = null;//inicializamos a null el objeto creado

    try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo); //abrimos el flujo de entrada de datos

    if (archivo != null){ //ponemos el condicional para que compruebe si el fichero esta vacio o no
        while (fis.available()>0){
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(fis); //establecemos la entrada de datos en el objeto
            m = (medicos) entrada.readObject(); //leemos los datos del objeto
            System.out.println(m.toString()); //imprimimos por pantalla los resultados
        }
        fis.close(); //cerramos el flujo de entrada
    }
 //capturamos las excepciones
}catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("Final del archivo");

}   catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error " + ex);
    }
}  

private void btnAceptarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

//primero validamos los datos 
String datos = "";

if (txtNIF.getText().equals("")){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese el NIF");
return;
}

if (txtNombre.getText().equals("")){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese el nombre");
return;
}

if (txtApellidos.getText().equals("")){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese los apellidos");
return;
}

if (txtTelefono.getText().equals("")){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese el telefono");
return;
}

//grabamos los datos
datos = txtNIF.getText() + txtNombre.getText() + txtApellidos.getText() + txtTelefono.getText() + " " + buttonGroup1.getSelection();
if (rbtnMujer.isSelected())
    datos += " Mujer";
else
    datos += " Hombre";
cbxGuardias.isSelected();
JcbxEspecialidad.setSelectedItem(datos + "\n");    


}
```

Os adjunto una visual de la interfaz gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas guardando objetos medico vacío siempre.

Comment: Aparte esto `if (archivo != null){ //ponemos el condicional para que compruebe si el fichero esta vacio o no` es erroneo. Así solo compruebas si el objeto File existe no si existe el fichero o esta vacío.

Comment: Es cierto @JDev. ¿Alguna opción para solucionarlo? Por ejemplo con: 
if(fichero.exists()){

Comment: Si, con eso valdría para lectura, para escritura necesitas tambien comprobar si se puede escribir. Para ello fichero.canWrite();

Comment: Creo que hay algo más que hago mal, porque me sigue dando error al mostrar. Es como si no se creara el objeto dentro del archivo, por lo tanto sigue lanzándome valores nulos al pulsar en mostrar. @JDev ¿No crees que falta algo en el código del botón "Aceptar" de la interfaz? porque ahí es donde debe escribir los datos de los JTextFiel en el objeto medicos para crearlo, y no lo hace. Voy a a intentar adjuntar más información. Muchas gracias por el aporte.

Comment: Yo diria que no estas llamando a guardar nunca.

Comment: @JDev ¿Cómo debo implementar el método añadirDatos (método de escritura), de la clase TareaGrafica07 en el botón "aceptar" de la interface para que me escriba el objeto con los datos que introduzco en los JTextField?

Comment: Lo primero sería rellenar el objeto medico y pasarselo al método añadirDatos por parametro. Por cierto es recomendable no usar ñ así que mejor cambia añadirDatos por annadirDatos o anyadirDatos.